# Dynamic Serializer Meta State Pollution Between Calls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a a dynamic serializer where I pass arguments from API calls into the serializer to filter specific fields from the relevant model class. I do this by leveraging the serializer's `__init__` function to directly set `self.Meta.fields`, which are otherwise a default set of fields I configured. Given a model with 3 fields, `id`, `description`, and `trigger`, when I make an unfiltered call, `/api/endpoint` I get what I expect, a list of json objects containing all the fields in the model. Then when I make a filtered call, i.e., `/api/endpoint?fields=id` I also get what I expect, a list result containing just the `id` field. However, when I make another unfiltered call I continue to get just a list of objects with only the `id` field. The only time from now on I get what I want is if I make a new filtered call. Here is my serializer code.

```
class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # id comes from `serializers.ModelSerializer`
    description = DescriptionSerializer()
    trigger = TriggerSerializer()

class SerializerA(BaseSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = kwargs.pop("fields", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if fields:
            self.Meta.fields = fields <--- this does NOT reset between calls

    class Meta:
        model = ImplIdDescriptionTriggerModelA  # there are more ImplModels...
        fields = '__all__'

class ParameterCaptureSerializer(BaseSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = BaseIdDescriptionTriggerModel
        fields ='__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        fields = None  <--- I could set this to DEFAULT_FIELDS and fix the problem, but what about the Meta state between calls? Whats that about?
        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request:
            params = request.query_params.get("fields")
            if params:
                # parses params and checks them against a set of allowed values or throws
                # an rest_framework exception with a response showing allowed fields
                fields = parse_fields(field_param=params, allowed=ALLOWED_FIELDS)

        if isinstance(instance, ImplIdDescriptionTriggerModelA):
            return SerializerA(instance=instance, fields=fields, context=self.context).data
        elif isinstance(instance, ImplIdDescriptionTriggerModelB):
            return SerializerB(instance=instance, fields=fields, context=self.context).data
        # new document subtypes must be added here
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError
```

The only solution I think makes sense to fix this and not introduce concurrency issues is to default the fields to the ALLOWED_FIELDS.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the allowed fields, you can check this in the DRF's docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

Answer (score 0):

At first, if you change `self.META` on `__init__` - you change object META for all instances.

At second - The information in DRF-Documentation is WRONG!!!! https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields - this is WRONG solution.

At third - I solve you problem in my talk there: https://youtu.be/IycQNgzFKwE?si=rbucOYDy-xK5jzfU&t=170

At last, working solution:

```
class DynamicFieldsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """Takes an additional `fields` argument"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None) or self.Meta.fields
        self.Meta = type('Meta', (self.Meta,) {'fields' : fields})
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```